# Use of preposition to demonstrate direction

Tags: prepositions

"Someone saw me coming in the opposite direction / someone saw me coming to the opposite direction??"Which one is correct and why?

Comment: How about _from_?

Comment: There needs to be a prior sentence specifying what 'opposite' is opposite to, but @Rattler's suggestion is almost certainly the one that will work.

Comment: @Rattler But can't I use "in"or "to"??

Comment: I would not use 'to'...'in' might work, depending on the context, which sadly we do not have. That said, the use is almost always 'from'.

Comment: "In" works. "To" doesn't. "From" works.

Answer (score -1):

> "Someone saw me coming in the opposite direction / someone saw me coming to the opposite direction"

In the first example, "in" means "observed direction from their position".  In the second example, "to" is unclear as to meaning.  Does it mean "going to" or "coming/going toward" something other than the observer?

Depending on intended meaning/description, either might be correct.  However, in general the direction one travels relevant to an observer is described with the preposition "in" or in this example perhaps "from".

Comment: If nothing/no one except the observer saw me coming then in that case what should be the use of preposition?

Comment: Probably "in" since the meaning of "opposite direction" has not been made clear.  It is assumed that the intended meaning is that "me" is approaching the observer from an opposite direction.  As such, use "in".

Comment: Still, "from" is preferable (see above).

Comment: @RobJarvis ... I agree with you that "from" is preferable.  However, that was not an option offered in the question, so I answered the question as asked but did want to suggest the better choice of "from" if an exchange in the questioner's work would be possible (e.g., if this question was in a class setting of "pick one or the other").  Thank you for emphasizing the preferable choice of "from."

Answer (score -1):

Seeing someone coming “in” the opposite direction suggests that they were travelling along parallel tracks, approaching each other.

Seeing someone coming “to” the opposite direction suggests someone turning around or otherwise manoeuvring so that they point in the direction either opposite their old direction or opposite the speaker’s direction or some reference direction.